# How to set Height Request for frame in code behind?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to dynamically create a frame in xamarin and wondering if it is possible to set the height request.

this is the code I have tried so far

```
Frame imageFrame = new Frame();

Frame.HeightRequestProperty = 70 ;
```

It gives this error:
A static readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a static constructor or a variable initializer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HeightRequestProperty`  is `BindableProperty` which you can't set value on it directly .

Modify your code as below

```
Frame imageFrame = new Frame();
imageFrame.HeightRequest = 70;
```

Or create binding

```
Frame imageFrame = new Frame();
imageFrame.SetBinding(Frame.HeightRequestProperty, "Height");
```